# curl in php (timeout) vs curl on the command line (works fine)

Tags: php, curl

I am currently trying to query an online API. Some example code:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw/playlists");
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 50,
    CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE      => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4
]);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch);
```

And I get: `curl(7) couldn't connect to host`

If you do the same thing on the CLI everything works:

```
$ curl -vvv "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw/playlists"

* About to connect() to gdata.youtube.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.194.113.1... connected
...
```

I first suspected IPv6 to be the problem, but I deactivated it. It doesn't help:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Comment: Is the webserver running on the same machine where you used curl fro the command line? Could be that the webserver cannot make outgoing connections. You could also try to run the PHP script from the command line.

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? I have encountered a similar issue:
(https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288893/wp-remote-request-does-not-return-a-response-from-from-server-when-ran-as-cron)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have `CONNECTTIMEOUT` it might not be a curl timeout.

The timeout could be for PHP execution.

You can try a `set_time_limit(0)` to get over this and see if it helps.

Also try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` to get over proxy configurations

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I added the config value but still get "can't connect to host". The timeout didn't solve it either. The equest normally runs for < 1s, so my timeout of 20s should be enough. But the behavior still is consistent: CLI works, php-curl doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a slightly different issue with a curl timeout via PHP but it was similar to your issue as it worked fine via the command line. I found that my PHP code worked once I set the `User-Agent` header as such:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)');
```

My only thought is that some sites are only issuing a response for what they consider valid User-Agents.